# how can I combine all these dicts in one?

Tags: python-3.x

My Code :

```
with open("Input_1.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
       Surname = line.split() [0]
       Item = line.split()[1]
       Amount=line.split()[2]
       dict_2 = {Surname : {Item: Amount}}
       print(dict_2)
```

So how can I combine all this dictionaries in one ?

Comment: This is what it prints :
{'Ivanov': {'aaa': '1'}}  
{'Petrov': {'aaa': '2'}}  
{'Sidorov': {'aaa': '3'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'aaa': '6'}}  
{'Petrov': {'aaa': '7'}}  
{'Sidorov': {'aaa': '8'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'bbb': '3'}}  
{'Petrov': {'bbb': '7'}}  
{'Sidorov': {'aaa': '345'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'ccc': '45'}}  
{'Petrov': {'ddd': '34'}}  
{'Ziborov': {'eee': '234'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'aaa': '45'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'paper': '10'}}  
{'Petrov': {'pens': '5'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'marker': '3'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'paper': '7'}}  
{'Petrov': {'envelope': '20'}}  
{'Ivanov': {'envelope': '5'}}

Comment: Side-note: You're splitting three times, pointlessly. A much better solution would be `surname, item, amount = line.split()` (slice to `line.split()[:3]` if some lines have extra fields you want to ignore silently). Will run significantly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the dict beforehand, and just assign individual keys, rather than making a new dict each time:

```
with open("Input_1.txt", "r") as file:
    dict_2 = {}
    for line in file:
        Surname = line.split() [0]
        Item = line.split()[1]
        Amount=line.split()[2]
        dict_2[Surname] = {Item: Amount}
    print(dict_2)
```